# Simplest way to serve dynamic content with .net (& preferably iis) without any form of asp.net / WCF / built in technology

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, .net-4.5

I'm trying to find the simplest way to server content over http (preferably through IIS but if required self hosted is an option). I'm not interested in using any form of web service or asp.net tech for this & am looking for the least overhead as i have no use for the added features.

The closest thing i found to my need is asp.net web api but it's still too featured / HL for me & doesn't really fit my need (i don't want actions mapped to urls, i want to receive the url & handle that myself, i know i could override that but once again it seems like a lot of overhead for nothing).

Just to be clear as i know it will popup : no i don't need any of the added functionality from those Tools including the obvious build in ones (i don't need authentication / security / sessions etc) all i need is

```
UrlCalled(string url)
{
    return ThisReturnsHtmlAndIDoEverythingElse();
}
```

Can you think of anything that would work? I thought about using http classes to host a server but there i miss out a lot of the functionality of IIS (making sure the website is always up etc).

.Net version is not a problem, it's for hosting on Windows server 2012, even beta versions are fine.

Comment: Can you provide some context for this requirement?

Comment: I'm writing a custom CMS to serve dynamic (as in it changes based on what's in the DB) data but not dynamic (as in diferent people see diferent things) pages. So i'm looking for the optimal way to send (generated by my system) html over the wire, while building upon the reliability of IIS, in .net, without any uneeded surface area exposed nor unused code slowing me done. The websites are managed externally (not through the website itself) by a WPF app that communicates with the DB directly.

Comment: I'm using razor (but not asp.net mvc) engine as a standalone to generate the HTML from templates & i want to manage the urls myself too, so currently in my design, if passed a string representing an url, i'm already able to do everything & return valid HTML, i'm just looking for the best & lowest overhead tech to go from some user typing an url to having .net code invoked with knowledge of the url, with this working in all case & no file required to match that url.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

In the end rolling my own server with HTTPHandlers was the best compromise i found as i couldn't find a low overhead solution with IIS, ended up serving semi dynamic content faster than iis serves static files so pretty happy about that.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a custom asp.net handler could fit you. A handler lets you work at the lowest possible level.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090(v=vs.85).aspx

In a custom handler you could read disk files (pages) and return them, build custom html strings and return them and do any other tasks you want.

What's more, by registering a handler to a specific custom extension, you could have your own "web execution engine", for example instead of "*.aspx" extension, your "pages" could have "*.foobar" or any other extension of your choice (including extensionless requests).

Comment: Actually i thought of handlers but i'm not sure it's fit for multiple reasons: 1) It still seems higher level than i'd like (since it can support session state etc) i'm assuming it's still doing some asp.net specific work that can be skipped in my case and 2) It doesn't do what i want (it lets me process the url i'm at, but what i want is to process all requests that come to a website, not those registered for a specific extention / pattern, and decide dynamically what i do with them)

Comment: Note that i may be wrong on #2 so if you have a counter example of how to make an Handler that answers on all requests (regardless of extention / pattern matching / file or path actually existing etc) then it may fit my need, but it needs to match everything that could possibly be a valid (not valid as in it exist, but valid as in http valid even if the url returns a 404) URL.

Comment: Yes, a handler can be registered for all possible extensions or not extensions at all. I think you just need to experiment more rather than ask questions.

Comment: Do you have a sample for this then, i could only find ways to register for specific extentions and / or valid path on the filesystem, how would i create an Handler that matches everything in such a way i can just return what i want based on the url? I did do some research on this (and it doesn't invalidate the question, the question isn't "how do i use httphandlers for" but "what is the lowest overhead tech i can do this with" i really doubt httphandlers are that being a part of asp.net for a use case that uses 0 feature from asp.net).